# C# .NET MVC Service Stack How to access custom user session from Authentication Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I have e .NET MVC5 Application with ServiceStack. In an AuthenticationFilter I want to check whether a particular property is in the session.

In AuthController:

```
var customerSession = SessionAs<CustomerUserSession>();
customerSession.property = "some value";
```

In Filter:

```
public class MyAuthFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        // I want to access that property here  
    }
}
```

My custom session implements AuthUserSession from service stack.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Controller needs to inherit `ServiceStackController` then you should be able to access the UserSession with:

```
var ssController = filterContext.Controller as ServiceStackController;
if (ssController == null) return;

var session = ssController.ServiceStackProvider.SessionAs<CustomerUserSession>();
```

Comment: SessionAs is a protected method of the class ServiceStackController so I don't think it can be used the way you've described.

Comment: @Nikola ok you should be able to use `ServiceStackProvider.SessionAs<CustomerUserSession>();`